# moving divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to move a div off the top of the screen using animate function and bring in another div with a callback after that has finished. both divs move together and I cant get them to move separately. even with the other div left out of my function it still moves both. thank you!

```
  $('#move').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate(
        {
            marginTop: '-500px'
                },
        2000,
         function(){

        }
           ); // end animate     
      }); // end hover      



    <div id="moveup">
  move up
    </div>

   <div id="moveright"> 
move right
    </div>
```

Comment: Give us a working demo of what you have so far please. You don't have a `#move` element in this HTML, and there is nothing in your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

They move together because they are positioned relatively, so when you set a negative margin on one, the other one follows it. If you want them to be independent, remove them from the document flow with `position:absolute;`

```js
$('#moveup').hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    marginTop: '-20px'
  },500,function(){

  }); // end animate     
}); // end hover
```

```css
#moveup, #moveright {
  position:absolute;
}
#moveup {
  top:50px;
}
#moveright {
  top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveup">move up</div>

<div id="moveright">move right</div>
```